# PayPal MassPay and AddressVerify: Which SDK do I use?

Tags: api, https, paypal

I'm getting some rather conflicting information from PayPal.  I've spent 2 hours on the phone with them today, and posted my questions on their forums, and I have not received one single solution.  So I am turning to SO since people here actually know what they're doing.

I am trying to add the AddressVerify and MassPay APIs to our website.  We are currently using the Payflow Pro (DirectPayment, etc) calls with no problems.  This uses our PayPal Manager login, password and vendor credentials for authentication via the HTTPS interface.  This is all written in PHP using NVP.

However, when I try to add the AddressVerify and/or the MassPay APIs using the HTTPS interface, all I get back is a PNREF and an error saying, "Invalid Tender."

On the forums, I see everyone using email addresses as logins, and a certificate key of some sort.  I called PayPal today to figure out how the heck to get that information, and the developer there said I don't use the login with the key and that I'm using the wrong SDK.  He told me where to get the Dev Guide and that I should use that instead.

However, the dev guide only outlines what we're already using, and I wasn't about to sit on the phone for another hour and 40 minutes.

**So my question is this:**
Am I just *missing something*, or did I just get some bad information?  I'm guessing it's the latter, because nobody there seemed to know squat about jack diddly.

1. Am I correct in assuming that the code ( [as outlined here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_MassPay_php.txt) ) is what I should be using?  If so, how do I obtain a signature key and presumably a new login & password?
2. If the dev guy from PayPal is correct and I should be using the HTTPS Interface, then how do I get that to work?  Because like I said above, all I'm getting from that is a PNREF and an error message saying, "Invalid Tender."

If anyone has any experience with this and/or some suggestions on how to get this stupid thing to work, I'd be forever greatful!

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody is interested in knowing, I received a response from the devs at PayPal:

> If you are using Payflow then you should be using the Payflow Pro SDK, it would require a User, Vendor, Partner, and Password in the credentials that get passed over.  It would also return a PNREF number.  If you are wanting to use Website Payments Pro, then your SDK would have either a API Username, API Password, API Signature, or an API Username, API Password,and API Certificate.  The AddressVerfiy API is an API that is available for Website Payments Pro/PayPal accounts not Payflow.  You can find all of the SDK's for both services here.  The Payflow SDK's are the ones at the bottom of the page.

So apparently MassPay and AddressVerify is part of the Web Payments Pro, which uses a different SDK than the Payflow Pro stuff.  And for this, you need to obtain a separate username, password, and certificate or key.  The Payflow Pro credentials will not work with this.

Hope someone else can benefit from my hours of wasted time!

Comment: How can i get User, Vendor, Partner, and Password on a test account